# How to save Flutter Custom Scroll View's scroll position?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, wrapper, android-scrollview

I have Material App with `CustomScrollView` and `BottomNavigationBar`, in `CustomScrollView` I have `SliverAppBar` and one page `Widget` (let say page1, page2 etc...) which represents `BottomNavigationBar's` current index, on every page `Widget` there is `SliverList` with some content

I have tried to put Keys and `ScrollControllers` inside `CustomScrollView` but it doesn't work as I expect, when navigating between pages Scroll position is initial.

```
class WrapperPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperPage createState() => _WrapperPage();
}

class _WrapperPage extends State<WrapperPage> {
  int _curIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages;
  List<PageStorageKey> _keys;
  List<ScrollController> _ctrls;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      // some pages pages
    ];

    _keys = List();
    _ctrls = List();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      _keys.add(PageStorageKey('scroll$i'));
      _ctrls.add(ScrollController());
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        key: _keys[_curIndex],
        controller: _ctrls[_curIndex],
        slivers: <Widget>[SliverAppBar(), _pages[_curIndex]],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            _curIndex = i;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _curIndex,
        items: [
          // some buttons
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My goal is to save `CustomScrollView's` scroll state while navigating pages.

Comment: Try to save the current state then reload it when `initState()` is called.

Comment: Should i save offset when navigating to new page and then restore offset when returning?

Comment: Yea. I think some states were not meant to be persistent on default. I think you should use a more global state save and restore it later

Comment: Oooh just now i found out that I have stream builders on pages where scroll state is lost

Answer (score 6):

Before use PageStorageKey you must create those storage. Try this simple scratch code:

```dart
class _WrapperPage extends State<WrapperPage> {
  int _curIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages;
  final bucket = PageStorageBucket();  // Create storage bucket

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: 
        // Wrap target widget with PageStorageBucket here.
        PageStorage(
          bucket: bucket,
          child: CustomScrollView(
            // Use `runtimeType` as unique value for key
            key: PageStorageKey(_pages[_curIndex].runtimeType.toString()),
            controller: _ctrls[_curIndex],
            slivers: <Widget>[SliverAppBar(), _pages[_curIndex]],
          ),
        ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int i) {
          setState(() {
            _curIndex = i;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _curIndex,
        items: [
          // some buttons
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me thanksa lot!